# Tag tooltip does not display correct number of subscribers

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-bubble

When hovering over the [qtp](/questions/tagged/qtp) tag in SO it says there are `0` subscribers. I know this is wrong since I subscribe to this tag for all SE sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed.  We weren't counting tags for "all sites", but now we do.